# File Manager is not working in Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: virtualbox, uefi, nautilus, windows-10, filemanager

Actually I opened **Disk usage tool**, too see that how much free space I've got, and then turned the computer off and now when I started it again all the directories on my desktop are gone even trash shortcut, I can't open the files using usual method I am have to use **nautilus** command and when I went back to that Disk usage tool again, two devices and locations are added one is *File System root* and the other one is */boot/efi*, and also to mention that before I turn off my laptop I also installed a **windows 10** in **virtualbox**, could it be the windows that is installed in virtual box that is affecting the system like this?
Any Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`File System root` and `/boot/efi` should always be there.

Perhaps it is because you turned off your desktop icon extension unintentionally? Run `gnome-extensions list` and find the one start with `desktop-icons` (on Ubuntu 20.04 it is `desktop-icons@csoriano`), then run

```
gnome-extensions enable desktop-icons@csoriano
```

and see if things become normal?